How to set up this integral properly?
I'm trying to find the most general expression to compute the total radiant flux (in watts) that a given collector surface $S_{C}$ receives from an emitter surface, $S_E$ (see poorly draw illustration bellow) using the basic quantites in radiometry:

Radian flux, $\phi$ (watts)
Irradiance $E$ (watts per squared meter)
Radiant intensity $I$ (watts per steradian)
Radiance $L$ (watts per steradian per meter squared)

.
Each area element on the emitter surface is radiating in all directions. In some directions, the intensity is stronger, while in others it is weaker—i.e., the intensity varies with direction.
Similarly, each element of the collector surface is receiving radiant flux from every direction, and the intensity also varies with direction.
I want to find the most general expression that provides the total radiant flux (in watts) received by the collector surface from the emitter surface. However, I'm having trouble setting up the integral to represent this.
It feels like these quantities should be enough to set up the problem, but I suspect I'm missing something. Since these are the most fundamental quantities in radiometry, I believe it should be possible to solve the problem with them.
Any help is appreciated.
Obs.
I'm disconsidering details related to reflection and transmission. All the radiation is absorbed by the emitter. We may not treat the emitter surface as a blackbody, $\epsilon$ is a variable function of position, wavelength and direction.
I don't even know how to start setting up this integral.

Please include the integral you have obtained so far.

And is the blackbody, or blackbody with emissivity $\epsilon < 1$, and if so, is it a function of frequency $\epsilon(\nu)$, which is normal, and/or angle (not related to Lambert's cosine law), so $\epsilon(\nu, \theta)$ ...which is unusual.

Added to the question.

Do you know how to write the expression for two arbitrary elements of area, one from each surface? (that is, two tiny arbitrarily oriented planar surfaces?)

This problem involves a lot-of-bookkeeping that is often glossed over--which I do regularly, even though I work in space borne radiometry, so I'm, giving it a shot with less than 100% confidence, with the hopes I figure it out once and for all. But bear with me as a plod through it.
Also: I will follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:SI_radiometry_units for guidance and symbols.
I'll define two surfaces, $S_T$ and $S_R$, where $T$ ($R$) stands for Tx (Rx) which mean any combination of Transmitter / Emitter / Source / Radiator/Reflector (Receiver / Antenna / Collector).
You asked for the most general expression to compute the radiant flux, $\Phi$, on a receiver surface $S_R$. Ok, that is for sure an integral over receiver elements $dA_R$, each at a position $\vec r_R$:
$$ \Phi_R = \int_{S_R} \frac{d\Phi_R(\vec r_R)}{dA_R}dA_R $$
Here $dA_R$ is differential area element of the receiver (and should have a direction: $d\hat A_R$).
It is intercepting a directional energy flux, aka Poynting vector, so:
$$ \frac{d\Phi_R(\vec r_R)}{dA_R}dA_R = \vec S(\vec r_R) \cdot d\hat A $$
According to the radiometry wikipedia page, the magnitude of the Poynting vector is called irradiance or flux density, $E_e$. It's going to be a function of position and frequency, which find by integrating over the emitting surface, $S_T$.
But first, consider an infinitesimal element of this surface, $dA_T$. It emits into a solid angle element $d\Omega_T$ at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the surface normal, at a frequency $\nu$ with infinitesimal bandwidth $d\nu$. The spectral flux can be written as:
$$ \frac{d\Phi(dA_T,\theta, d\Omega_T, \nu, d\nu)}
{d\Omega_T} = L(dA_T, \theta, \nu, d\nu)dA_Td\nu\cos\theta
$$
The spectral radiance $L\ \ \ ({\rm W\cdot sr^{-1}\cdot m^{-2}\cdot Hz^{-1}})$ does not depend on $\theta$ for blackbody radiation, but we are not making that assumption.
At this point, you need to integrate that over $S_T$ with the Poynting vector aligned with $\vec r_R - \vec r_T$, and
$$ d\Omega_T \propto \frac{dA_R}{|\vec r_R - \vec r_T|^2} $$
while also integrating over frequency.
I'll have to finish this later, pls comment.

Wouldn't $ E_e = \mathbf S \cdot \mathbf{\hat n} $? where $\hat{\mathbf n}$ is the normal to the surface and $E_e$ is the irradiance?

I think so. Wiki says $E$ per Hz per sr is a directional quantity....so when does it turn into a scalar, or does a signed scalar determine a direction relative to a normal?
